# Sort the div in alphabetical order using data attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, sorting

I want to sort the html div in alphabetical order using data attribute value.
 I have the following code and would like to know, how can this be achieved

```
<div id="aphaOrder">
    <div class="value"  data-site="olark">olark</div>   
    <div class="value"  data-site="snapengage">snapengage</div> 
    <div class="value"  data-site="helponclick">helponclick</div>
    <div class="value"  data-site="hangouts">hangouts</div>
    <div class="value"  data-site="atlass">atlass</div> 
    <div class="value"  data-site="hipchat">hipchat</div>   
    <div class="value"  data-site="chat hip">chat hip</div>
    <div class="value"  data-site="force">force</div>
    <div class="value"  data-site="sugar sms">sugar sms</div>
    <div class="value"  data-site="capsule">capsule</div>
    <div class="value"  data-site="highrise">highrise</div>
    <div class="value"  data-site="nimble">nimble</div>
    <div class="value"  data-site="batch">batch</div>
    <div class="value"  data-site="book crm">book crm</div>
    <div class="value"  data-site="solve">solve</div>
    <div class="value"  data-site="insightly">insightly</div>
    <div class="value"  data-site="pipeliner">pipeliner</div>
    <div class="value"  data-site="shopify">shopify</div>
    <div class="value"  data-site="wordpress">wordpress</div>
    <div class="value"  data-site="Magento">Magento</div>
</div>
```

```js
var alphabeticallyOrderedDivs = $('.value').sort(function(a,b){
    return $(a).attr('data-site') > $(b).attr('data-site');
});
$("#aphaOrder").html(alphabeticallyOrderedDivs);
```

This is code is not giving the proper result. Please help me with this.

Comment: The comparison function is supposed to return a number, not a boolean.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use [`String.prototype.localeCompare`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare)

**[JSFIDDLE here](http://jsfiddle.net/c7m44gzv/)**

---

```
var alphabeticallyOrderedDivs = $('.value').sort(function(a, b) {
    return String.prototype.localeCompare.call($(a).data('site').toLowerCase(), $(b).data('site').toLowerCase());
});

var container = $("#aphaOrder");
container.detach().empty().append(alphabeticallyOrderedDivs);
$('body').append(container);
```

Answer (score 2):

This should work:-

```
        $("#aphaOrder .value").sort(function (a, b) {
            if ( ($(a).attr("data-site").toLowerCase() > $(b).attr("data-site").toLowerCase()) )  { 
                return 1;
            } else if ( ($(a).attr("data-site").toLowerCase() == $(b).attr("data-site").toLowerCase()) ){
                return 0;
            } else {
                return -1;
            }
        }).each(function () {
            var elem = $(this);
            elem.remove();
            $(elem).appendTo("#aphaOrder");
        });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/0bs5mu6e/2/

Comment: thanks for the reply. but the output was not in alphabetical order

Comment: See edit. The comparison function is supposed to return a number, not a boolean. Previous code would work fine in firefox but not in chrome. This one should work in both.

Answer (score 1):

You are try to get the attribute `data-value`. There is no property like that. Check **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/0wvca596/)**

Try this:

```
return $(a).data('site').toLowerCase() > $(b).data('site').toLowerCase();
```

or

```
return $(a).attr('data-site').toLowerCase() > $(b).attr('data-site').toLowerCase();
```

Output will be:

```
atlass
batch
book crm
capsule
chat hip
force
hangouts
...
```

Comment: thanks for the reply. but the output was not in alphabetical order

Comment: ??? Did you checked my jsfiddle? That is totally in alphabetic order. Please point me where is not that.

Comment: pls see this link [http://i61.tinypic.com/o70ymd.png] . In jsfiddle, the first div is `<div class="value"  data-site="highrise">highrise</div>`. It is not showing **atlass** div first.

Comment: Can you just give me your jsfiddle link? If you check mine, that works.

Comment: This code would work fine in firefox but not in chrome.

Comment: You are right, I did not tested with other browsers.

Answer (score 1):

This is a modified version that includes an option to sort descending.

```
var alphaOrder = function(sortDescending){
var $container = $('section.grid'),
    $containerInner = $container.find('> ul'),
    alphaOrder = $container.find('li').sort(function(a, b) {
        // return String.prototype.localeCompare.call($(a).data('name').toLowerCase(), $(b).data('name').toLowerCase());
            var an = a.getAttribute('data-name'),
                bn = b.getAttribute('data-name'),
                pos = sortDescending ? -1 : 1,
                neg = sortDescending ? 1 : -1;

            if(an > bn) { return pos; }
            if(an < bn) { return neg; }
            return 0;
    });
    // console.log(typeof alphaOrder);
$containerInner.detach().empty().append(alphaOrder);
$container.append($containerInner);
```

}